# Struct in C. Unknown type name,

Tags: c, structure, codeblocks

I am new to structures in C but as far as I know, my code is "correct". I am using Codeblocks but I've also compiled it in DEV C++ and I got the same error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct film{
   int year;
   char  title[30];
   char  director[30];
   char  main_char[30];
} ;


int main ()
{

    film venom={ 2018, "Venom", "Ruben Fleischer", "Tom Hardy" };

    printf("Year: %d\n", venom.year);
    printf("Title: %s\n", venom.title);
    printf("Director: %s\n", venom.director);
    printf("Main Character: %s\n", venom.main_char);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

I have not idea what is the error about. [image]

Comment: You need to use `struct` keyword while declaring(`struct film venom`).

Comment: Please do not post pics. Post text as text.

Answer (score 5):

This is C, not C++, so structs have their own namespace.

You need to either write `struct film venom;`, or use the traditional `typedef`:

```
typedef struct film film;
```

which is often attached to the struct definition itself;

```
typedef struct film{
   int year;
   char  title[30];
   char  director[30];
   char  main_char[30];
} film;
```

Comment: OH! I see, thanks! Is there a difference between using typedef or write struct film venom?

Comment: @User_1492 There's no difference.

Comment: @User_1492 Actually there is no difference as typedef in C only creates an alias.

Comment: @P__J__: C 2018 6.2.3 “Name spaces of identifiers” says there are separate name spaces for label names; tags of structures, unions, and enumerations; members of structures or unions (a separate name space for each structure or union); and all other identifiers.

Comment: I usually add an `_t` to the typedef, to clearly see what's meant. Here it would be fine using `film_t`.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct film
{
    ...
} ;
```

and then

```
struct film f;
```

or

```
typedef struct
{
    ...
} film;
```

and then

```
film f;
```

Comment: Youv even can combine both of them: `typedef struct film
{
    ...
} film;`, but I'm not sure if it's advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Also I would advise you to use "s_" and "t_" to make a difference between the structure and its alias and use the "t_" alias as a type when you declare the structure.

```
typedef struct s_film {
   int   year;
   char  title[30];
   char  director[30];
   char  main_char[30];
} t_film;
```

And then use it the following way:

```
t_film venom = {2018, "Venom", "Ruben Fleischer", "Tom Hardy"};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use:

```
struct film venom={ 2018, "Venom", "Ruben Fleischer", "Tom Hardy" };
```

Or you can `typedef` the struct

```
typedef struct {
   int year;
   char  title[30];
   char  director[30];
   char  main_char[30];
} film;
```

Which allows you to use `film` instead of `struct film`